# Чтение RSS в кодировке CP_1251 на android

Tags: android, кодировка, cp1251, utf-8, rss

Создаю читалку новостей для своего сайта! Новости в БД хранятся в кодировке CP_1251. Программирование для android только начал изучать, поэтому разбираюсь на ходу. Один хороший человек скинул мне исходники своей читалки новостей. Но она заточена под UTF_8. Соответственно новости с любого сайта на утф парсятся нормально, а при работе с моим сайтом приложение выдает ошибку "ошибка загрузки". Скоро сайт переведу на UTF_8. А по сему нужна ВРЕМЕННАЯ мера по изменению кодировки. Подскажите как это реализовать. Возможные варианты:
-незначительные изменения кода (чтобы потом легче исправить обратно)
-сторонние сервисы изменения кодировки
-создание второй БД и перегон новостей через нее с перекодированием (возможно бред)
-другие манипуляции

Comment: судя по фото - коллега! только погон не видно... как я понял tokenstring - в эту переменную получили новости в utf-8... а вот что дальше происходит? конкретно вторую строку не понял... пардон за глупый вопрос но в java я совсем чайник

Comment: привет связистам :) а по примеру по ходу я ошибся
вот посмотрите тут http://habrahabr.ru/qa/11449/

Comment: Вообще-то я космонавт )), но это неважно, по делу... то, что советуют по вашей ссылке,

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "windows-1251");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

то что у меня

    Xml.parse(this.getInputStream(), Xml.Encoding.UTF_8, root.getContentHandler());

Возможно я не тот кусок вставил, но на лицо разница в синтаксисе... или я че-то не догоняю?

Comment: пишите в скайп the_sekrets помогу

Comment: @kornalexandr2 хм а как вы угадали про космические войска, не по пейзажу же?) ну вообще зависит от  от того как вы считываете

Comment: вот кусок...
public class NewParser {
 protected InputStream getInputStream() {
  URL feedUrl = null;
  try {
   feedUrl = new URL("http://in-army.com/rss/content/6/feed.rss");   
  } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
   feedUrl = null;
  }
  try {
   return feedUrl.openConnection().getInputStream();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   return null;
  }
 }
не пойму куда вставлять эти строки... и похоже я немного другими методами пользуюсь

Answer (score 2):

```
InputStream is= this.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, "cp1251");
Xml.parse(reader, root.getContentHandler());
```

Comment: огромное нечеловеческое спасибо! отлично работает

Answer (score 0):

читает новости с сайта ,только лишние теги и символы .как от них избавиться .хотелось видеть тему и текст содержание.

```
package android.rss;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;

public class RSSFeed extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String rssResult = "";
    boolean item = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView rss = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rss);
        try {
            URL rssUrl = new URL("http://rfs.ru/rss/news.rss");
            // http://feeds2.feedburner.com/Mobilab
            //http://go-football.org/news/rss.xml
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();            
            RSSHandler rssHandler = new RSSHandler();
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(rssHandler);
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
            xmlReader.parse(inputSource);
            rss.setText(rssResult);
        } catch (IOException e) {rss.setText(e.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException e) {rss.setText(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {rss.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, 
Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("item"))
                item = true; 

            if (!localName.equals("item") && item == true)
                rssResult = rssResult + localName + ": " ;

        }

        public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, 
String qName) throws SAXException {

        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            String cdata = new String(ch, start, length);
            if (item == true)
                rssResult = rssResult +(cdata.trim()).replaceAll("\\s+",  " ")+"\t";

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```